# Azure Data Factory -> Copy from SQL to Table Storage (boolean mapping)

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

I am adding pipeline in Azure Data factory to migrate data from SQL to Table storage.
All seems working fine, however i observed that bit column is not getting copies as expected.
I have a filed "IsMinor" in SQL DB.

If i don't add explicit mapping for bit column as is then, it is copied as `null`
If i set it as 'True' Or 'False' from SQL, it is copied as `String` instead of Boolean in TableStorage.

I also tried to specify type while mapping the field i.e. "`IsMinor (Boolean)`", however it didn't worked as well.
Following is my sample table

[image]

I want the bit value above to be copied as "Boolean" in Table storage instead of String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried copy the boolean data from my SQL database to table Storage, it works.

As you know, SQL server does't support boolean data type, so I create table like this:
[image]

All the data preview look well in Source dataset:
[image]

I just create a table `test1` in Table storage, let the data factory create the PartitionKey and RowKey automatically.

Run the pipeline and check the data in `test1` with Storage Explorer:
[image]

From the document [Understanding the Table service data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-the-table-service-data-model), Table storage do support Boolean property types.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you, i observed that initially i had queries BIT value, however as it was a nullable field and i didn't noticed that.